# Plot the last 100 points in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, gif

The following gif is created with gnuplot and Fortran. However, now I want to do the same using only Python (animation form matplotlib mainly).

I can generate a gif with Python but I don't know how to generate something like the righthand side gif (you plot also the last 100 points), the evolution in phase space.

Any help will be apreciated,

Thanks

[image]

Gnuplot code for the gif:

```
set term gif size 1000,600 animate  delay 1000 loop 0 
set output "animacio.gif"
cd 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop'
datafile ="P7-1718-b-res.dat" 


do for[i=1:5000:10]{

set multiplot

set size 0.5,0.8
set origin 0.0,0.0
set title "Evolució de l'angle girat i velocitat angular (t)"
set xrange[0:50]
set yrange[-pi:pi]
set xlabel "t (s)"
set ylabel "Angle girat, v_{ang}"
set key below
plot datafile index 9 every ::1::i with line linewidth 4 t"Posició angular" ,datafile index 9 every ::1::i u 1:3 with line linewidth 4 t"V_{ang}"

set origin 0.5,0
set size 0.5,0.8
set title "Evolució en l'espai de fases"
set yrange[-pi:pi]
set xrange[-pi:pi]
set xlabel "Angle girat(rad)"
set ylabel "Velocitat angular(rad/s)"
set key below
if (i>101) { 
plot datafile index 9 every::i::i u 2:3 t"" ps 3,datafile index 9 every::i-100::i u 2:3 w l t"" } 
else {
plot datafile index 9 every::i::i u 2:3 t"" ps 3}
unset multiplot
}
```

And assume your data have three rows (time,position,angular velocity) at index 9.

Comment: You need to show the code you are using to plot these.

Comment: While you may be lucky in which case someone can translate your complete code into some other language, it would usually be required to limit your question to a specific problem; this would mean to show the python code you have a problem with and clearly state at which point you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use Matplotlib animation to make it work.

I have done something "similar" to your data, but of course, as I haven't got the data file, it is not equal. The code is the following one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

w = 1.
t = np.linspace(0,10,200)
x = np.cos(w*t)
v = -w*np.cos(w*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

line_1, = ax[0].plot([], [], 'b-', lw=2)
line_2, = ax[0].plot([], [], 'r-', lw=2)
ax[0].set_xlim([0,50])
ax[0].set_ylim([-np.pi,np.pi])

line_3, = ax[1].plot([], [], 'g-', lw=2)
star_3, = ax[1].plot([], [], 'g*')
ax[1].set_xlim([-np.pi,np.pi])
ax[1].set_ylim([-np.pi,np.pi])

def animate(i):
    line_1.set_data(t[:i],x[:i])  # update the data
    line_2.set_data(t[:i],v[:i])
    nLast = 20
    idFrom = i-nLast if(i-nLast >= 0) else 0
    line_3.set_data(np.cos(t[idFrom:i+1]),np.sin(t[idFrom:i+1]))
    star_3.set_data(np.cos(t[i]),np.sin(t[i]))
    return line_1,line_2,line_3,star_3

# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line_1.set_data([], [])
    line_2.set_data([], [])
    line_3.set_data([], [])
    star_3.set_data([], [])
    return line_1,line_2,line_3,star_3

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, len(t)), init_func=init, interval=100, blit=True)
#anim.save('Plot_last_nLast.mp4', fps=15)
#anim.save('Plot_last_nLast.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can save the animation in a GIF (required Imagemagick) or as a MP4 movie if you have ffmpeg to use it as writer of the animation.
But that's another issue